# Strange Webdriver issue with Mitmproxy

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, timeout, webdriver, mitmproxy

Here's a condensed version of my code, showing an issue with webdriver and mitmproxy:

```
from libmproxy import controller
from libmproxy import proxy
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
import time


# traffic inception
class HttpMitmReporter(controller.Master):
    def __init__(self, proxy_server):
        controller.Master.__init__(self, proxy_server)

    def run(self):
        try:
            return controller.Master.run(self)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.shutdown()


# setup browser with proxy settings etc.
def setup_browser():
    global driver
    proper_setup = False

    proxy_con = "127.0.0.1:8088"
    my_proxy = Proxy({'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
                      'httpProxy': proxy_con,
                      'ftpProxy': proxy_con,
                      'sslProxy': proxy_con,
                      'noProxy': ''})

    while not proper_setup:
        try:
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=my_proxy)
            driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
            driver.set_script_timeout(20)
            proper_setup = True
        except Exception as exception:
            print exception
            try:
                driver.quit()
            except Exception:
                time.sleep(3)


driver = None

# start proxy
config = proxy.ProxyConfig(
    cacert=os.path.expanduser("~/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca.pem")
)
server = proxy.ProxyServer(config, 8088)
reporter = HttpMitmReporter(server)
mitm_proxy = Process(target=reporter.run)
mitm_proxy.start()

setup_browser()

# urls to test
urls = [
        'http://support.microsoft.com/common/survey.aspx?showpage=1&scid=sw%3Bde%3B3663&altStyle=narrow&renderOption=OverrideDefault&fr=1',
        'http://outlook.com/',
        ]

# visit sites
for url in urls:
    print url
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    except Exception as ex:
        print ex
        driver.quit()
        setup_browser()

# terminate browser and proxy
driver.quit()
mitm_proxy.terminate()
```

If you execute this you should see that firefox is loading forever outlook.com and the timeouts are never triggered.
The problem only occurs with mitmproxy. I have tested another proxies and they worked on these urls, but I can't use them, because they either cannot inspect SSL traffic or just provide raw data output. However I figured out mitmproxy should be the best solution, if it would work properly together with webdriver.
Furthermore I have tested this with mitmproxy started on shell -> same issue
and with webdriver with Java -> same issue
Moreover this happens on other urls like fc2.com sometimes.

Here's a little overview of my configuration:
- Linux Mint Petra x64
- python 2.7
- Mitmproxy 0.10.1
- Selenium 2.41.0
- Firefox 28

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?
Why does this just happen with mitmproxy?
Additionally I'm interested in alternatives to inspect http and https traffic with selenium.

**Update with FlowMaster:**

```
from libmproxy import flow
from libmproxy import proxy
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
import time


# traffic inception
class HttpMitmReporter(flow.FlowMaster):

    def run(self):
        try:
            flow.FlowMaster.run(self)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.shutdown()

    def handle_request(self, r):
        f = flow.FlowMaster.handle_request(self, r)
        if f:
            r.reply()
        return f

    def handle_response(self, r):
        f = flow.FlowMaster.handle_response(self, r)
        if f:
            r.reply()
        return f


# setup browser with proxy settings etc.
def setup_browser():
    global driver
    proper_setup = False

    proxy_con = "127.0.0.1:8088"
    my_proxy = Proxy({'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
                      'httpProxy': proxy_con,
                      'ftpProxy': proxy_con,
                      'sslProxy': proxy_con,
                      'noProxy': ''})

    while not proper_setup:
        try:
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=my_proxy)
            driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
            driver.set_script_timeout(20)
            proper_setup = True
        except Exception as exception:
            print exception
            try:
                driver.quit()
            except Exception:
                time.sleep(3)


driver = None

# start proxy
config = proxy.ProxyConfig(
    cacert=os.path.expanduser("~/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca.pem")
)
state = flow.State()
server = proxy.ProxyServer(config, 8088)
reporter = HttpMitmReporter(server, state)
mitm_proxy = Process(target=reporter.run)
mitm_proxy.start()

setup_browser()

# urls to test
urls = [
        'http://support.microsoft.com/common/survey.aspx?showpage=1&scid=sw%3Bde%3B3663&altStyle=narrow&renderOption=OverrideDefault&fr=1',
        'http://outlook.com/',
        ]

# visit sites
for url in urls:
    print url
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    except Exception as ex:
        print ex
        driver.quit()
        setup_browser()

# terminate browser and proxy
driver.quit()
mitm_proxy.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are instantiating mitmproxy wrongly. Have a look at https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/flowbasic, you definitely need a FlowMaster instance, not controller.Master.

Comment: I changed my code using FlowMaster as you proposed (see update), but the same issue is occuring. Btw Firefox has changed to version 29.

Comment: If I use an external browser https is not working (with installed CA) and the same issue is occuring. But if I use controller istead of flow https is working and there's no problem in the external FF.

Comment: However selenium is too buggy atm even without any proxy. Thus I already wrote my own casperjs wrapper, which is working way more better.